# Deleting objects from Core Data that doesn't exist in an array

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Core Data object like the following.

```
DummyObject
{
  objectID:<objectID>
  objectName:<objectName> 
}
```

And I have 1000 of these `DummyObject`s saved. I have also an array `objectArray` which contains 100 of these `DummyObject`s.

I want to run a query that would delete all the `DummyObject`s which are not in this array.

Comment: You could just try a predicate like the following for your fetch request `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (self IN %@)", yourArray];` Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment

You could just try a predicate like the following for your fetch request

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (self IN %@)", yourArray];
```

Using it together with a `NSFetchRequest` allows you to retrieve the objects that are not in the array.

Obviously, `yourArray` contains objects of type `DummyObject`.

To delete,

```
// fetch request with predicate...
NSArray* results = // execute the fetch request

for(NSManagedObject* dummy in results) {
   [context deleteObject:dummy];
}

// save here...
```

where `results` is the array of objects retrieved by your fetch request.

Comment: So this answer says you need a unique id: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24495150/826435. So I'm not 100% sure if this answer is valid.